# When copying commerce databases from server A to B what are the places that need to be updated?

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-server

When dealing with commerce we see that it stores connection strings in the databases, for example in the MSCS_Admin the table resourceprops stores all sorts of connection information.
Now say you want to restore all commerce databases from server A into server B and just update connection strings, what are the places one need to update? What are all the databases impacted and which ones need to be updated?
Do I need to manually build SQL scripts for that to update each row with the new connection or is there an easier way to do so?

Update: This is Sitecore 8.2 update 3 with Commerce 8.2.1(initial release)

Comment: Could you please add info about sitecore commerce/commerce server version?
Because added answers related to Sitecore Commerce 9. I think you mean early version of Sitecore Commerce

Answer (score 1):

Please see this blog.. it would help you.

https://jitendrasitecore.wordpress.com/2019/05/11/change-database-password-sitecore-9-x/

you have to change the password in the configuration files as well as you have do change server name in the sitecore databases as well.

For Commerce end you have to make the following changes:

https://jitendrasitecore.wordpress.com/2018/12/13/change-default-password-sitecore-commerce/

Answer (score 0):

Look for 'Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.SQL.EntityStoreSqlPolicy' in Bootstrap/Global.json -> This should point to Global DB
Then look for same policy in data/Environments/Plugin.SQL.PolicySet-1.0.0.json -> This should point to Shared DB

And do this for all your Commerce Engine roles(Authoring, Minions, Shops, Ops..)
Then you need to Re-Boostrap Commerce Engine using Postman Collections